# PLATO & JS99'er

Tags: programming, plato

Has anyone out there managed to load a PLATO PHM 3122 cartridge by Control Data into the [JS99'er](http://js99er.net/) emulator?

That way a user could place all of the PLATO Lesson Disks on a cloud location (e.g., OneDrive) and have access to one of the better home computer teaching & review applications that was ever available for a stand-alone home computer!

Having access to a TI99/4A emulator through the internet may be a unique method of re-introducing the more than 3,000,000 original TI99/4A purchasers and users to a beloved retro home computer!

Discussing its availability on social media like Facebook could go a long way towards its revival.

Comment: If you are just interested in running PLATO, on [cyber1](http://www.cyber1.org/) there is an emulation of the original system by Control Data (not Ti-99 based, and older than the Ti-99).

Comment: And if you are interested in emulating PLATO on a Ti-99, it looks like it's emuated by [MAME](http://www.mame.net/) (which is not JS99, so again not your question...)

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of activity around PLATO in the retro-computer scene lately thanks to one particular person, Thom, who has been porting a PLATO terminal to many retro computers including the 99/4A.  He has a website with status for all the systems: https://www.irata.online/

As for running PLATO itself on js99er specifically, I see the original PLATO cartridge in js99er's software list and I just loaded it without problems.  If you have trouble with js99er, the author of the emulator is a very active member of the TI-99/4A subforum of the AgariAge forums.